# Sum in variable expression in total column with a condition

Tags: variables, jasper-reports, sum

I want to get sum of a column without negotive values.
1500 + (-1000) + 2000 = 3500 (without negative values)

[image]

Sum is with negative values.I want without negative values. All negative values should in each rows. Only last total should be without negative values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to know how are you creating your report by I think you will need something like (not tested but will put you on the right direction):

```
<variable name="total" class="java.lang.Integer" calculation="Sum">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{netSalary}>=0) ? ($F{netSalary}) : 0]]>
</variableExpression></variable>
```

Comment: Glad it helped! Can you mark the response as the right one?